# Only one truthy bool value for one foreign key in postgre

Tags: postgresql, constraint

Lets assume we have 2 database tables (entites).
The first is named A and the second one is named B.
There are 1:N (where N > 0) relationship (so every record in table A is in relation with 1+ records in B table).

**Table A** (for simplicity assume there is just id in this table, other table columns are not relevant for this question)

**Table B**

- id (bigint) <- primary key
- defaultForA (boolean, default = false)
- a_id (bigint) <- foreign key for table A record

Is it possible to set table contraint that will check there is **only one truthy value in defaultForA column for every present a_id value**?
For example we have 2 records in table A (with IDS 0,1)

And 4 records in table B

*id, defaultForA,a_id*

0,true,0

1,false,0

2,true,1

3,false,1

**This is completely fine state. For each A record I have one "default" value from B table**
The constraint **should not** allow me to add following record to table B

4,true,0

Because there is alredy record linked to record 0 in table A that have *defaultForA* property set to true

Comment: You can use 2 EXCLUDE constraints for this. Exemple:                                           `create table t
(
 id   int primary key,
 defaultForA  bool,
 a_id  int
);
alter table t add constraint exclude_both_true exclude using btree (a_id with =) where (defaultForA);
alter table t add constraint exclude_both_false exclude using btree (a_id with =) where (not defaultForA);`  NB: this solution is different from the link to SQL Server discussion. This solution does not depend on foreign keys but is using a Postgresql only type of consraint: the EXCLUDE constraint.

Comment: It doesn't need EXCLUDE constraint though. It can be done with a partial/filtered UNIQUE index. The linked answer has that option, too: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX is_FavoriteChild
  ON Child (ParentID)
  WHERE IsFavorite = 1 ;`

Comment: You just have to change the table/column names and adjust for the different type (boolean vs int): `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX is_default_for_a ON b (a_id) WHERE defaultForA ;`